# Batch to extract download address from many txt to a new txt file

Tags: batch-file, command, findstr

I have a lot of txt files containing the following words, `download` and `address`.

I only want the download address for `1fichier` website so I write a batch as follow:

```
set pa="C:\download"
for /r %pa% %%a in (*.txt) do type %%~fa|Findstr "hxxps://1fichier.com/" >> getdownload.txt
```

getdownload.txt result:

```
h53tnzhh0514dsvr00700.xjl5xtqg.part1.rar : hxxps://1fichier.com/?oesuw9ty9lkhh2wbj5us
h53tnzhh0514dsvr00700.xjl5xtqg.part2.rar : hxxps://1fichier.com/?exgrcaza0i2cjmwpyvpb
```

I only want the `hxxps://1fichier.com/?oesuw9ty9lkhh2wbj5us` and `hxxps://1fichier.com/?exgrcaza0i2cjmwpyvpb`, 
not the file names, 
`h53tnzhh0514dsvr00700.xjl5xtqg.part1.rar :`, and `h53tnzhh0514dsvr00700.xjl5xtqg.part2.rar :` parts

How I can get the result as following:

```
hxxps://1fichier.com/?oesuw9ty9lkhh2wbj5us
hxxps://1fichier.com/?exgrcaza0i2cjmwpyvpb
```

I have about `20` txt files which contain the following content

```
115 download address： 

ed2k://|file|h53tnzhh0514dsvr00700.xjl5xtqg.part1.rar|12884901888|2B958C84EF5C4BDE5B1031DC9ACAAE7C|h=NFRHBEWYTMQNYAQ3FVHEU5UFEJ2CMZ44|/
ed2k://|file|h53tnzhh0514dsvr00700.xjl5xtqg.part2.rar|1135932776|87EF320F80F201AB66B19E23D9AA999F|h=X3MKSWI7ZLBKOJDXBC3CKJVSALEGSO7S|/


1fichier download address：

h53tnzhh0514dsvr00700.xjl5xtqg.part1.rar : hxxps://1fichier.com/?oesuw9ty9lkhh2wbj5us

h53tnzhh0514dsvr00700.xjl5xtqg.part2.rar : hxxps://1fichier.com/?exgrcaza0i2cjmwpyvpb
```

Comment: Take a look at the [`for /F` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)...

Comment: `for /f "tokens=3" %%a in (...`

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and most efficient way, for me would be to use `FindStr` directly:

```batch-file
@Echo Off & SetLocal EnableExtensions
Set "pa=C:\download"
(   For /F "Tokens=2*" %%G In (
        '%__AppDir__%findstr.exe /SIL "hxxps://1fichier.com/" "%pa%\*.txt" 2^>NUL'
    ) Do @If "%%G" == ":" Echo(%%H)>"getdownload.txt"
```